# How can i fix the output of this recursion function

Tags: php

```
function my_recurse($id,$tree=array())
{


    $hols = array();


    $overall = array();
    $asd = $this->db->get_where('story', array('story_id'=>$id))->row_array();

    if(isset($asd['story_id'])){

    $preds = explode(',',$asd['story_pred']);

            if($preds[0] != 0)
            {

                $hols[] = $preds[0];

                $hols = array_merge($tree, $hols);
                $this->my_recurse($preds[0],$hols);

            }


    }    
    print_r($hols);
}
```

say for example i have this tree

story1 NULL
story2 story1
story3 story2
story4 story3

and when i enter story4 as my id in the function it always returns the story3 and not story1,story2 and story3. dont know why it reverses the output after the recursion happens. any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Bit hard to understand. Short variable names make code hard to read if you're unfamiliar. Also, what is this supposed to be achieving?

Comment: yeah.. it reverses the output.. say for example a tree like this story1->story2->story3->story4 calling the my_recurse(story4) i expected the output would be array(story1) for the 1st recurse array(story1,story2) for the 2nd and array(story1,story2,story3) for the last one but when i print_r after each recurse it goes like this array(story1,story2,story3) then array(story2,story3) and array(story3) so when im returning the hols it always returns the story3

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say if this will be easy or possible without knowing your database structure, but  you don't need recursion to find the path of a tree node to the root - you can do this with a self join.  Also, you should avoid making a query in a recursive function.  If you can describe your table structure I can attempt to show you how to get a result set that is the tree path in order.

Comment: my database structure is like this. story_id: 4 story_pred: 2,3,4 story_name: story16 im doing implode and explode to store the predecessors coz i dont  prefer much creating table specifically for predecessors and successors

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that its *passing* the current preds up to the parent hence the reverse tree. Instead it should be *getting* the preds from the parent

This should work if I understood your requirements clearly

```
<?php
function my_recurse($id) {

    $hols = array();
    $overall = array();

    $asd = getFromDB($id);

    if(isset($asd['story_id'])){
        $preds = explode(',',$asd['story_pred']);

        if($preds[0] != 0) {
            $hols[] = $preds[0];
            $hols = array_merge(my_recurse($preds[0]), $hols);
        } else {
            return $hols;
        }   

        print "preds of {$id} : ";
        print implode(', ', $hols) . "\n";
        return $hols;
    }   
}   

function getFromDB($id) {
    $data = array(1 => array('story_id'=>1, 'story_pred' => '0'),
                  2 => array('story_id'=>2, 'story_pred' => '1'),
                  3 => array('story_id'=>3, 'story_pred' => '2'),
                  4 => array('story_id'=>4, 'story_pred' => '3'),
                  );  

    return $data[$id];
}   

my_recurse(4);
```

Running the script above..

```
$ /usr/bin/php recurse.php
preds of 2 : 1
preds of 3 : 1, 2
preds of 4 : 1, 2, 3
```

PS: Please add your sample input, output and expected output. It took me 15 minutes to try understanding your problem.